# Минусы хранения статей в файлах, а не в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, cms, веб-программирование

Некоторые CMS используют для хранения статей не базу данных, а обычные текстовые файлы. Хотелось бы узнать, какие в этом случае могут возникнуть проблемы при большом количестве статей.

Пока единственное, что приходит на ум - это поиск, но при желании и его можно ускорить, если создавать индекс.

PS. Одним таким движком я давно уже пользуюсь и доволен, но статей на данный момент не очень много.

Comment: При грамотной организации хранения, что бы много файлов в одном каталоге не лежало минусов особо не вижу. Ну разве что в nix системах есть ограничения на кол-во файлов в одной файловой системе. Но его реально сложно достигнуть

Comment: есть еще документо-ориентированные бд

Comment: 1) Резервная копия. Придётся файлы копировать отдельно от базы. Если в это время происходят транзакции, то файлы могут оказаться немного не синхронизированными с базой. 2) Индексация. Многие базы поддерживают полнотекстовый поиск и соответствующие индексы. По своим полям они точно ищут и индексируют, а вот внешние файлы - кто знает? Хотя конечно можно сделать поля для хранения индекса. 3) Переключение с одной методы получения/записи данных на другую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Резервная копия. Придётся файлы копировать отдельно от базы. Если в
   это время происходят транзакции, то файлы могут оказаться немного не
   синхронизированными с базой.
2. Индексация. Многие базы поддерживают полнотекстовый поиск и
   соответствующие индексы. По своим полям они точно ищут и
   индексируют, а вот внешние файлы - кто знает?   Хотя конечно можно
   сделать поля специально для хранения индекса (грубо говоря из текста
   извлечь ключевые слова и поместить в это поле).
3. Переключение с одной методы получения/записи данных на другую.   Это
   просто неудобство. В некоторых случаях оно так и так будет (если
   пользоваться не привычным SELECT/INSERT, а каким-то более
   эффективным на больших данных поточным интерфейсом базы данных)

В любом случае приходится предпринимать дополнительные усилия по синхронизации записей в БД и внешних файлов. Где это действительно важно, требуется задействовать базы данных и файловые системы с поддержкой распределённых транзакций, координировать транзакции бд и фс.

Comment: Про индексы погорячился. У самого в postgrese полнотекстовый поиск и дополнительное поле для него создаётся в любом случае: хоть данные в базе, хоть во внешнем файле.